# Inserting images in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: image, wysiwyg, ckeditor

At the moment I'm using CKeditor. It looks very good and is fast. But it lacks the ability to insert images from the server.

I don't need to upload, only get a list of files and select the image to insert it.

Is there a plugin, or maybe easy way to integrate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The newset version CKEditor 3.x does not have a builtin file upload function. It has to be provided as a plugin. You can buy the CKFinder plugin at www.ckfinder.com (That's what you see in the demo)

Answer (score 0):

FCKEditor's (I did not switch to CKeditor, but I am sure it is the same there) image button does allow inserting images from server. You can see in on the [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) - click the button and choose Browse Server.

Normally, user has ability to upload and then insert images he uploaded, but you can configure it so that upload is disabled and only existing images from the server can be inserted into the post.

I know exactly how to do that in FCKeditor, I am sure it is still that easy in the newer version.

Comment: Yeah. In the demo it works; but when I download the package itd does not. 2.4 looks a bit messy; but I'll give it a try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE have that plugin. [Demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/imagemanager/integrated_with_tinymce.php)